# Why operator ?: lost lvalue-ness if second or third argument is throwing expression?

Tags: c++

In C++ operator ?: can be an lvalue if second and third argument is lvalue of same type, for example:

```
int foo = 0, bar = 1;
bool condition = true;
(condition ? foo : bar) = 42; // correct
```

Also it is possible to throw something in this operator:

```
bar = (condition ? foo : throw 42); // still correct
```

But this code doesn't compile because left expression is not an lvalue:

```
(condition ? foo : throw 42) = bar; // compile error
```

I check this fact in C++ standart and read this:

> The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression
>   (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and **is an rvalue**.

What explanation for this rule?

Comment: `condition ? foo : bar = 42; ` is `condition ? foo : (bar = 42);`.

Comment: Thanks, I add braces. My question is still actual.

Comment: @dyp Yep, looks like this is fixed in C++14.

Comment: If you condition is true, the result is `foo = bar`. But if it is false, will result in `throw 42 = bar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [CWG defect 1560](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1560). Quoting the defect report:

> A glvalue appearing as one operand of a *conditional-expression* in
>   which the other operand is a *throw-expression* is converted to a
>   prvalue, regardless of how the conditional-expression is used: [...]
>   This seems to be gratuitous and surprising.

This is fixed by the resolution of [CWG 1550](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1550), now [expr.cond]/2.1 says:

> [If] The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) *throw-expression*; the result is
>   of the type and value category of the other.

So it should work with a recent compiler.

Comment: As a fellow programmer, I request that no one ever use this.  I like that it was a compile error. ;-)

Comment: @MobyDisk it can be useful in member initialization list, for example:

struct SomeStruct { SomeStruct(int x) : m_x(x > 0 ? x : throw "error") {}
int m_x; };

Comment: @maxim.yurchuk but this case works for now, only issue would be to initialize a reference.

Answer (score -1):

`throw` has lower precedence than `?:` and `=`.  What you're effectively saying is

`condition ? foo : throw (42 = bar);`

Obviously `42` is not assignable as an rvalue.

Source:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

(Answer refers to syntax of original question...)

Comment: Sorry, I forget the braces. Now I fixed the question and add them.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious what OP asked, he made mistake in syntax, that could be mentioned in comment, but not in answer